# How/What to use to make a 3D sitemap

Tags: 3d, three.js, sitemap

.Hello, I am trying to create a more interesting sitemap for a page I am currently updating. The company that owns the site is huge (the page they use has 50+ individual departments, each with sub-departments etc) so I was wanting to make a visual representation of all the pages in the site to help people look around for the right department, sub-department, or sub-sub-etc. department.

Ideally the user would either be able to use a search in the top corner of the page where all matches on the map are highlighted and then be able to click on the link as well as see the path to that page via the map. Additionally each of the very top departments should extend, from the center, on a different z axis to allow the maximum amount of information to be displayed while still being as organized as possible.

I am happy to learn whatever language or libraries would be needed, I'm just at a loss as to where to even begin. I thought about Three JS as I've heard and read about how amazing it is for 3D images but I do not see an obvious example of its use that I could ply to this attempt (if you have any please put it as an answer).

TLDR - I'm trying to build a 3D sitemap but do not know what to learn to make it, please advise.

Thank you for any input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://olafureliasson.net/uncertain

An example of using 3 dimensional navigation. You are correct that Three.js/canvas can do this for you but wouldn't there be an easier solution: something like http://tympanus.net/Development/MorphingSearch/ that allows you to give the wow factor without having such a large learning curve

Comment: YEEEEEESSSS This is perfect! Thanks so much!